# 2 Foreign Keys Referencing the Same Primary Key in Data Warehouse

Tags: powerbi, foreign-keys

In a data warehouse, a fact table cannot have 2 foreign keys from the same primary key?

I have a **city_id** which has foreign keys **origin_city_id** and fk **destination_city_id** . When in MYSQL, the relationship was successful. But there is a problem when in POWER BI.

This is my table

dim_city |

- city_id
- city_name

fact_transaction |

- Transaction_id
- origin_city_id
- destination_city_id
- price

Or maybe there are suggestions for changing the table?

In MYSQL both FK are referenced by the Primary Key. But when I try in power BI. Only one of the relations can be active so the other FK is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I can say it's not uncommon for a fact table to have multiple foreign keys referencing the same primary key in a dimension table however it can be tricky in Power BI.

So it's either you create a composite key in your dimension table by combining both `origin_city_id` and `destination_city_id` into a single field then, have a single foreign key in your fact table referencing this composite key.

Or just use a bridge table if the relationship between `origin_city_id` and `destination_city_id` is many-to-many, you might need a bridge table to represent this relationship in a explicit way.

If you also think denormalizing your fact is a possibility just duplicate the city information for both origin and destination(with this alternative you can avoid relationships).